# How to fit multiple rows in linear regression model in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

While fitting the linear regression in `R`, how can I take into account that for each subject in the dataset there are multiple rows, not one? like this dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
        x = c(10,10,12,22,25,22,18,12,19,21,11,23,15,18,10),
        y = c(55,53,34,43,44,33,52,53,64,67,66,77,55,65,49))
```

Comment: This is really a stats question, not a programming question - but your samples aren't independent so you need to look at some sort of repeated measures or blocked design to account for this.

Comment: well you could do something like this: